# how to use variables conditionally in styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to conditionally change the UI of my component in styled components, but I found myself repeating myself a lot.
this is what is happening right now:

```
color: ${props => (props.isProductPage ? color('white') : 'reset')};
background-color: ${props =>
  props.isProductPage ? color('primary', 'main') : 'reset'};
font-size: ${props => (props.isProductPage ? '1.4rem' : 'reset')};
font-weight: ${props => (props.isProductPage ? '400' : 'reset')};
```

but I want to have all these in a variable and import that variable conditionally, but I could not find out what am I doing wrong. This is what I am looking for.

```
const ProductPageAddToCard = `
color: ${color('primary')};
background: ${color('primary', 'main')};
font-size: ${textSize('medium')};
font-weight: ${textWeight('medium')}
`;

export const StyledAddToCardWrapper = Styled.div`
 button {
  ${props => (props.isProductPage ? ProductPageAddToCard : '')}
 }
`
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'css' export from 'styled-components' to create a reusable mixin.
Here is a small example:

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

// ...

const ProductPageMixin = css`
  color: red;
  background-color: orange;
`;

const HomePageMixin = css`
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  ${(props) => props.isProductPage && ProductPageMixin}

  ${(props) => props.isHomePage && HomePageMixin}
`;
```